# Why am I getting wrong signs in the odd indexes of my Fourier coefficients?

Tags: matlab

I've been trying to calculate step by step the DFS of some signals in a single period, first by calculating the coefficients and then calculating the entire series.

With each step I plot in a graph what I've been doing in order to see it visually.
This is my coefficient calc function:

```
function [Ak, k] = FourierCoeffGen(x, n, N_per)
    W0 = (2*pi/N_per); 
    k = -N_per/2:N_per/2-1; % Index range for the Fourier coefficients
    Ak = (1/N_per)*x*exp(-1*j*W0*(n.')*k); 
end
```

Now after getting my vector of coefficients I try to reconstruct the original signal using:

```
function x = DiscreteFourierSeries(Ak, k, N_per)
    W0 = (2*pi/N_per);
    expo = exp(1j*W0*(k.')*k);
    x = Ak*(expo.');
end
```

After doing all of those I plot the 3 graphs (original signal, coefficients and the reconstructed signal) in graphs and try to understand what I got:

```
% Example 2 - x[n] = 1 for -5 < n < 5, 0 elsewhere
N_per = 20;
n2 = -N_per/2:N_per/2-1;
%x2 = (n2 > -5) & (n2 < 5);
x2 = zeros(1,20);
x2(7:15) = 1;


% Plot original function 2
subplot(3, 1, 1);
stem(n2, x2);
xlabel('n');
ylabel('x[n]');
title('Original Function 2');


% Calculate Fourier coefficients for Example 3
[Ak2, k2] = FourierCoeffGen(x2, n2, N_per);

%Plot coefficients for function 2
subplot(3, 1, 2);
plot(n2, Ak2);
xlabel('n');
ylabel('A[k]');
title('X[n] Coefficients');

% Reconstruct signal for Example 3
x2_reconstructed = DiscreteFourierSeries(Ak2, k2, N_per);

% Plot reconstructed function 2
subplot(3, 1, 3);
stem(n2, x2_reconstructed);
xlabel('n');
ylabel('x_{reconstructed}[n]');
title('Reconstructed Function 2');

sgtitle('Original Functions vs Reconstructed Functions');
```

My issue is that the coefficients that I get using this simple discrete dirac step function (-1 for -5<n<5 and 0 otherwise) with a period of 20 - all have the wrong sign in the **odd indexes** of the output coefficient vector.

I honestly tried debugging it, trying to refresh my math knowledge but I cannot find a decent reason for is it happening:

[image: Odd indexes have the wrong sign]

Would appreciate some help

I have tried switching up the input and playing with it, but it seemed to be pointless.
The math should be ok, I looked up all the formulas (please correct me if I'm wrong).

EDIT - I have tried starting my indexing to be from 0 to 20 instead of -10 to 10 (even though both should work fine as it is a periodic function), and yet the odd signed indexes still seem to be with the wrong sign (notice here how X=1 should be Y=-0.315688)
[image]

Comment: k should go from 0 to N-1, not from -N/2 to N/2-1. The same is true for n. If you do that, you should get the same signs as `fft`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks for the quick answer! But why should it matter where do I start my period? If I calculate the values from -10 to 10 or 0 to 20? It's a periodic function anyway. Also, I tried changing the code as you said while of course changing my input to be  x2 = zeros(1,20); x2(1:5) = 1; x2(17:20) = 1; - To support the new way of calculation, and it seems that the coefficient graph that I plot still gives me the wrong signs on my odd indexed coefficients (added image in my post).

Comment: If you do `fft(x2)/length(x2)`, you'll see exactly the same values as `Ak2`. Not sure why you think you need a negative value there.

Comment: @CrisLuengo but shouldn't the coefficients of a function like I provided return look like Dirichlet kernel? Which jumps from negative to positive every iteration?

Comment: In the continuous domain case, a box function transforms to a sinc function. By sampling the box function, you'd get an infinite set of sinc functions, shifted by the sampling frequency, and added together. This should still more or less look like a sinc function, though depending on the ratio between the sampling frequency and the box width, the overlapping copies would have a larger or smaller effect on the tail of the sinc in the central, unique part (between - and + Nyquist frequency). (contd.)

Comment: (contd.) By windowing, you sample the frequency domain. Depending on the size of the window, you get more or fewer samples within that central part. With some samplings, few samples will be negative (as is your case), in other cases more samples will be negative. There are two factors to tweak: number of samples within your window, and width of the box within the window. I suggest you play with these and see the effects.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I indeed solved it, my calculations were right and the only thing I didn't take an account of was a half phase shift in my X scale (time). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a solution to exercise 5.2 in

**book Digital Signal Processing in MATLAB**

2nd edition

authors: Vinay K. Ingle, John G. Proakis

```
% example 5.2 periodic square pulses
% time resolution: N and L, increase it to improve also 
% frequency resolution
% Xt=dft2(xn,N) is like [Xt,k]=dft()  but allows to play with

L=15;N=50;n=[0:1:N-1]
xn=[ones(1,L),zeros(1,N-L)]
M=100
[Xt,k]=dft2(xn,N,M)
% k=[-N/2:N/2]
magXt=abs(Xt);phXt=angle(Xt)*180/pi
stem(k,magXt)

% zei=find(magXt<0.00001);phXt(zei)=zeros(1,length(zei))

subplot(3,1,1);H_s1=stem(n,xn,'filled');set(H_s1,'markersize',3)
% title('1 cycle of x(n)','fontsize',10)
% ylabel('amplitude');ntick=[n3(1):5:n3(N3),N3]';axis([-1 N3 -6 6])
% set(gca,'XTickMode','manual','XTick',ntick,'fontsize',8)

subplot(3,1,2);H_s2=stem(k,magXt,'filled');set(H_s2,'markersize',3)
% axis([-1,N3,min(magXt3),max(magXt3)])
% title('|Xt3(k)|','fontsize',10);ylabel('magnitude')
ktick=[k(1):5:k(N)]';set(gca,'XTickMode','manual','XTick',ktick)

subplot(3,1,3);H_s3=stem(k,phXt,'filled');set(H_s3,'markersize',3)
% title('angle(Xt3(k))','fontsize',10);xlabel('k');ylabel('degree')

ktick=[k(1):5:k(N),N]';axis([-1 N -180 180])
% set(gca,'XTickMode','manual','XTick',ktick)
% set(gca,'YTickMode','manual','YTick',[-180 -90 90 180])
```

[image]

This solution does not show the odd coefficients deviations that somewhere in  `DiscreteFourierSeries` and `FourierCoeffGen` functions seem to be introduced.

The support function I use is

```
% Discrete Fourier Transform Series coefficients
function [Xk,k]=dfs(xn,N)
n=[0:1:N-1]
k=[0:1:N-1]
WN=exp(-1j*2*pi/N)
nk=n'*k
WNnk=WN.*(-nk)
Xk=xn*WNnk
```

Hope it helps.